# I have accidentally mounted 20GB disk under /usr. Due to which i'm unable to boot or even not able to enter single user mode. Is there any way?

Tags: single-system-image

I have accidentally mounted 20GB disk under /usr. Due to which i'm unable to boot or even not able to enter single user mode. Is there any way?

Even I have removed the disk No 2 under VMware console. But still I'm unable to boot.

Comment: Can you mount the disk if you attach it to a new VM and boot a live cd? I wonder if you overwrote `/usr`

Comment: Please tag your question with operating system distro and version. This could be a number of flavors of Linux, BSD, or UNIX, and the solution is specific to which.

Comment: Thank you Bert. Yep i accidentally mounted with the fstab entries. Though we don't have live cd in the VMware console.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the rescue mode with the boot option `rd.break=initqueue`.

Run the following commands to initiate the volume manager and mount the system root

```
pvscan all
vgscan all
lvscan all
mkdir foo
mount -t xfs /dev/mapper/rootvg foo


vi foo/etc/fstab
```

Delete the entries of /usr mount point; save & Quit;

```
exit; reboot;
```

That is it. Now os loads successfully.

Comment: Thank you a lot..